# Can I develop for Android Tablets without an actual tablet device?

Tags: android, emulation, tablet

I bought the Augen Gentouch78 to start dabbing in development for Android tablets, but this device is gravely excruciating to use (and I'm returning it). Is there a way to configure the emulator to tablet specs (namely Samsung Galaxy Tab)??

Answer (score 2):

You could create an AVD with similar hardware and Android 2.2. The main difference is the resolution (which is 600x1024), so you can try configuring your AVD this way:

[image]

Just keep in mind the AVD limitations; for instance, they don't support multitouch.

Answer (score 0):

Install the GALAXY Tab addon by Samsung, it adds a API-8 Galaxy Tab target to the options list in the AVD creation screen.

The Honeycomb tablet require a API level 11 or 12 on WXGA skin.